# Function to remove duplicates from a unsorted linked list

Tags: glib

I try to write a function to remove duplicates from `GList *list` unsorted linked list and return `GList *list` without duplicates:

```
GList *remove_dup (GList *list)
{
    GList *a, *b, *dup;
    a = list;

    /* Pick elements one by one */
    while (a != NULL && a->next != NULL) {
        b = a;

        /* Compare the picked element with rest of the elements */
        while (b->next != NULL) {
            /* If duplicate then delete it */
            if (a->data == b->next->data) {
                /* sequence of steps is important here */
                dup = b->next;
                b->next = b->next->next;
                g_list_free_1 (dup);
            } else  /* This is tricky */ {
                b = b->next;
            }
        }
        a = a->next;
    }

    /* return list without duplicates */
    return list;
}
```

example `name.list` with duplicates:

```
A
A
B
C
B
A
```

after use `remove_dup` function:

```
name.list = remove_dup (name.list);
```

`name.list` without duplicates:

```
A
B
C
```

-> but it seems that `remove_dup` return same `name.list` with duplicates.

That is my mistake in this code?

Comment: Please try to add a more accurate problem description than _"does not work"_. Is the problem in finding duplicate data pointers or removing list nodes?

Comment: added more accurate problem description

Answer (score 1):

What about this (haven't tested it but it should work):

```
GList *remove_dup (GList *list)
{
    GList *a, *b, *dup;

    /* Pick elements one by one */
    for (a = list; a; a = a->next) {
        /* Compare the picked element with rest of the elements */
        for (b = a->next; b;) {
            dub = b;
            b = b->next;
            if (a->data = dub->data)
                list = g_list_delete_link (list, dub);
        }
    }

    /* return list without duplicates */
    return list;
}
```

While this O(n2) function is fine with short lists it becomes inefficient with longer ones. Perhaps you would like to use a different algorithm like:

```
GList *remove_dup (GList *list)
{
    GList *a, *dup;
    GHashTable *set;

    set = g_hash_table_new(NULL, NULL);

    /* Pick elements one by one */
    for (a = list; a;) {
        dub = a;
        a = a->next;
        if (g_hash_table_contains(set, dub->data)) {
            list = g_list_delete_link (list, dub);
        } else {
            g_hash_table_add (set, dub->data);
        }
    }

    g_hash_table_unref (set);

    /* return list without duplicates */
    return list;
}
```